# Print all Placement of an array in a certain order

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

This is a question that has already appeared a few times (*cf [Print all the permutations of a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989689/print-all-the-permutations-of-a-string-in-c)*) however what i'm having trouble with is a bit different and i'm having an hard time figuring an answer.

I'm currently working on a function that would apply another function on all permutations of an int array. I decided to use backtracking and it resulted in the code below.

```
void ft_perm(int *mat, int size, int i) // Initially called with i = 0
{
    int j;

    j = i;
    if (i == size)
    {
        f(mat, ...) // any function that applies itself on mat
    }
    else
    {
        while (j >= 0)
        {
            ft_swap(mat, i, j); // function that swaps i and j
            ft_perm(mat, size, i + 1);
            ft_swap(mat, i, j); // backtrack
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the order in which the function is applied is not exactly what i'd need and i can't figure out how to make it work correctly. I would need 'f'  to be applied in an order where the smallest number is always at the leftmost.

For example, using a 3 number array, the current function will apply 'f' on
012->021->210->102->120 while what i'd need would be to apply 'f' on 
012->021->102->201->120->210.

But that's specific, in a nutshell, my question is "Is it possible to manipulate the permutation order using backtracking ?"

Thanks for your help and well, sorry for the long and wobbly question.

*Ps : Thanks for the edit !*

Comment: I think it'll help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928236/print-all-permutation-in-lexicographic-order

Comment: Thanks ! I'm currently reading trough the answer but the thought process is very probably the same one i should use. I'll try that right now !

Comment: Ive been searching for two days but i really cant figure it out... My case is pretty unusual. Is there anybody that has an idea ?